# Facebook returning cover id as int, turns into float on my machine

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

http://screencast.com/t/XFRuJtLg

Why would they not send this through as a string? My system converts this to a float and then I lose the accuracy of the id because it is rounding poorly.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

If you’re having this problem while using json_decode(?) – then just set the option `JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING` as 4th parameter in the function call.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

It is appearing as a float because you are suffering from integer overflow.

You will need to look into how your development environment handles 64 bit integers. 
You might need to specially add a bigint library, if there is not native support.
BCMath is one such library

"If PHP encounters a number beyond the bounds of the integer type, it will be interpreted as a float instead."
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php